# Reuse parent symbols in child module

Tags: oop, raku

I am seeking to re-use the same role/class names in a child module as in its parent. You know, like a specialization.

The aim is to be able to re-use the same script code for both the parent and child Series variants by simply changing `use Dan` to `use Dan::Pandas` at the top.

I am trying to stick to role rather than class compostion where I can so that the behaviours can be applied to other objects with eg. `class GasBill does Series;`

Here is the MRE:

```
me@ubuntu:~/spike# tree
.
├── lib
│   ├── Dan
│   │   └── Pandas.rakumod
│   └── Dan.rakumod
└── spike.raku
```

Dan.rakumod:

```
  1 unit module Dan;
  2 
  3 role Series is export {
  4     method no { "no" }
  5 }
```

Pandas.rakumod:

```
  1 unit module Dan::Pandas;
  2 
  3 use Dan;
  4 
  5 role Series does Dan::Series is export {
  6     method yo { "yo" }
  7 }
```

spike.raku:

```
  1 use lib './lib';
  2 use Dan::Pandas;
  3 
  4 my $s = Series.new;                  #version 1                      
  5 #my $s = Dan::Pandas::Series.new;    #version 2 "fqm"
  6 
  7 say $s.no, $s.yo, $s.^name;
```

My version 1 says:

```
No appropriate parametric role variant available for 'Dan::Series':
    Ambiguous call to '(Dan::Series)'; these signatures all match:
      (::$?CLASS ::::?CLASS Mu $)
      (::$?CLASS ::::?CLASS Mu $)
  in block <unit> at spike.raku line 4
```

My version 2 says:

```
Could not find symbol '&Series' in 'Dan::Pandas'
  in block <unit> at spike.raku line 5
```

I am trusting that raku does have a way to do this, but darned if I can work it out!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR** You need a solution that avoids having two roles with the same full name.

## Golf

```
role R {}
role R {}
R.new
```

displays:

```
No appropriate parametric role variant available for 'R':
    Ambiguous call to '(R)'; these signatures all match:
      (::$?CLASS ::::?CLASS Mu $)
      (::$?CLASS ::::?CLASS Mu $)
```

(See [Gut-referencing warning when composing stubbed role](https://github.com/Raku/old-issue-tracker/issues/5791) for a bit more discussion of the error message.)

## A solution

1. Just `Dan`.

   - `Dan.rakumod`:

     ```
     unit module Dan;

     role Series is export { method no { "no" } }
     ```
   - `spike.raku`:

     ```
     use lib '.';

     use Dan;

     my $s = Series.new;

     .say for $s.?no, $s.?yo, $s.^name;
     ```
   - Running `spike` displays:

     ```
     no
     Nil
     Dan::Series
     ```
2. Introduce `Dan::Pandas`.

   - Alter `Dan` so variant modules can `use` it *without* them *importing* `Dan`'s *unqualified* `Series` symbol into their lexical scopes.

     (Because otherwise `Dan`'s unqualified `Series` symbol ends up being in their lexical scopes *as well as* their *own* unqualified `Series` symbol, and you get the "Ambiguous call" error.)
   - `Dan`:

     ```
     unit module Dan;

     role Series is export { method no { "no" } }

     class Dan::Variant-Export-Dummy-Type is export(:Variant-Exports) {}
     ```

     The change is the last line, a dummy declaration with a new export tag. (Introducing the new tag some cleaner way is left as an exercise for readers.)
   - `Dan::Pandas`:

     ```
     unit module Dan::Pandas;

     use Dan :Variant-Exports;

     role Series does Dan::Series is export { method yo { "yo" } }
     ```

     The change is using the new `:Variant-Exports` tag with the `use Dan ...` statement. This stops `Dan`'s `Series` role being imported under that unqualified name into `Dan::Pandas`.
3. User programs will now work as expected/wanted.

   - Just change the `use` statement in `spike.raku`:

     ```
     use lib '.';

     use Dan::Pandas;

     my $s = Series.new;

     .say for $s.?no, $s.?yo, $s.^name;
     ```
   - Running with just this change for user programs:

     ```
     no
     yo
     Dan::Pandas::Series
     ```
   - Note how there's no need for programs using using these modules to know about the `:Variant-Exports` tag. That's just an internal detail of the `Dan` module and the `Dan::Pandas` etc modules that lets them avoid the unintended role variant duplication problem shown at the start of this answer.

Comment: raiph - many thanks for this ... your answer was slightly offbeam (no doubt due to my poor naming of methods in the op) in that ```method no``` should always work (either directly or inherited by the child) and that ```method yo``` should only work when the child is there since it is the specilization. I have adopyed your approach and applied export controls ... see 'My Solution' below for the synthesis of yoru answer (also with a nudge from @codesections)

Comment: @p6steve "your answer was slightly offbeam ... in that `method no` should always work" Ah. I've updated my answer accordingly so that the `.no` call always works (by adding `does Dan::Series` in the `Dan::Pandas` module).

Answer (score 5):

If I'm understanding correctly, you don't need/want to use the non-specialized role in the final module (that is, you aren't using the `Series` defined in `Dan.rakumod` in `spike.raku` – you're only using the specialized `Series` defined in `Pandas.rakumod`).  Is that correct?

If so, the solution is simple: just don't `export` the `Series` from `Dan.rakumod` – it's still `our` scoped (the default for roles) so you can still use it in `Pandas.rakumod` exactly the way you currently do (`Dan::Series`).  But, since it's not exported, you it won't create a name clash with the non-prefixed `Series`.

Comment: that's the right reading of the question - however, I do want other scripts to be able to ```use Dan;``` (ie the non-Pandas version) successfully

Comment: @p6steve other scripts can still `use Dan` just fine in exactly the same way that `Pandas.rakumod` does – they'll just need to use the full `Dan::Series` name (rather than just `Series`) to refer to the `Dan::Series` (again, just like `Pandas.rakumod` does).  If that's too verbose, they can always alias it in the file with something like `constant Series = Dan::Series` after the `use` statement.

Comment: codesections - thanks for the reminder that FQNs do not rely on the export process... this is a keystone for my combined solution (see below) ... since I only have one vote for Answer, please forgive that I will award to @raiphs answer this time ... since that closed the loop.

Answer (score 1):

My Solution

Taking the advice of @codesections [that FQMs can be used without `is export`] and @raiph [that you can qualify the export with e.g. `is export(:ALL)`], then - yes - there is a neat way to do this.

viz. https://docs.raku.org/language/modules#Exporting_and_selective_importing

Turns out that this is low touch (just change two lines) and, as I originally hoped, something that raku designers have anticipated.

Here is the code from my OP adjusted...

Dan.rakumod:

```
  1 unit module Dan;
  2 
  3 role Series is export(:ALL) {    #<== added the selective export
  4     method no { "no" }
  5 }
```

Pandas.rakumod (no change):

```
  1 unit module Dan::Pandas;
  2 
  3 use Dan;
  4 
  5 role Series does Dan::Series is export {
  6     method yo { "yo" }
  7 }
```

spike.raku:

```
  1 use lib './lib';
  2 #use Dan::Pandas;     #\ either of these work
  3 use Dan :ALL;         #/ <== use :ALL to get 'Series'
  4 
  5 my $s = Series.new;
  6 
  7 say $s.no, $s.yo, $s.^name;  #No such method 'yo' if Pandas not used
```